# Node js: What is the best way of rendering error without rendering whole page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my application, data is rendered initially when page is loaded and in the same page I have module to add data. I am trying to check if some fields are empty while  adding data and render them in the page.

What happened is, when I render the page with errors while adding data, those data which were loaded initially during page load get lost because I am rendering page with just error not with whole data agai

API that loads data during page load

```
router.get('/model', function(req, res, next) {

  var tvs = [];
  var refrigerators = [];
  var washingMachines = [];

  db.query("SELECT * FROM model", (error, results, fields) => {
    if(results) {
      for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++){

        if(results[i].category === 'refrigerator'){
          refrigerators.push({id: results[i].id, model: results[i].name});
        }
        else if(results[i].category === 'tv') {
          tvs.push({id: results[i].id, model: results[i].name});
        }
        else if(results[i].category === 'wm') {
          washingMachines.push({id: results[i].id, model: results[i].name});
        }
      }
      res.render("home/model", {refrigerators: refrigerators, tvs: tvs, washingMachines: washingMachines});
    }
    if(error) throw error;
  });
});
```

API that checks errors(if any) during adding data,

```
router.post('/add-model', function(req, res, next) {

  var model = req.body.modelName;
  var category = req.body.category;

  var errors = [];


  //check if any fields are empty
  if(!model) {
    errors.push({'error_message': 'Model name cannot be empty!'});
  } 
  else if(!category) {
    errors.push({'error_message': 'Category cannot be empty!'});
  }

  if(errors.length > 0){
    console.log("flow is coming here!");
    res.render('home/model', {errors: errors});
  } else {
    //check if model already exit
    res.end('it is working as expected!');
  }

});
```

I don't think it is good to write whole logic again inside api that adds model(in this case).
What may be the best practice to render page with error without affecting previously loaded data?

Comment: you might want to try flash : https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash

Comment: First of all most of the errors are pretty basic like not present, which can be easily avoided by using a front end library like https://jqueryvalidation.org/ even can use HTML validations. Instead of post would suggest using AJAX for this. Had a similar issue in the past and the result was I end up using some other framework which supports features like advanced rendering and keeping sessions messages inbuilt.